# Using inputprocessor so an object follows the x-axis of the touch-input, object goes crazy

Tags: java, libgdx

So i want it so that when user is touching the screen, the object follows the x-axis of the touchpos. When I'm doing this with polling (Gdx.input.getX()) it works like it has to. But with input processor, when touching on the screen, the object goes crazy all over the screen. I dont really get why. Here is the code

Player.java :

```
public class Player extends Entity
{
    MyInputProcessor input;

    public Player(float x, float y, Sprite sprite)
    {
        super(x, y, sprite);
        input = new MyInputProcessor();
        Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(input);
    }

    public void update(final Application app)
    {
        handleInput(app);
        super.update();
    }

    public void handleInput(Application app)
    {
        if (input.touchDown)
        {
            Vector2 touchPos = app.viewport.unproject(input.screenTouchPos);
            position.x = touchPos.x - sprite.getWidth() / 2;
        }
    }
}
```

MyInputProcessor.java :

```
public class MyInputProcessor implements InputProcessor
{
    public boolean touchDown = false;
    public Vector2 screenTouchPos;

    public MyInputProcessor()
    {
        screenTouchPos = new Vector2();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean keyDown(int keycode)
    {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean keyUp(int keycode)
    {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean keyTyped(char character)
    {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean touchDown(int screenX, int screenY, int pointer, int button)
    {
        touchDown = true;
        screenTouchPos.set(screenX, screenY);
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean touchUp(int screenX, int screenY, int pointer, int button)
    {
        touchDown = false;
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean touchDragged(int screenX, int screenY, int pointer)
    {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean mouseMoved(int screenX, int screenY)
    {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean scrolled(int amount)
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This line

```
Vector2 touchPos = app.viewport.unproject(input.screenTouchPos);
```

does not provide you a copy of the unprojected vector. It is modifying the input Vector2 and handing you back the same reference. Since your input processor only resets its Vector2 when you touch down, then as long as you hold your finger down, your Player class will unproject the same vector on every frame. Calling unproject on the same vector more than once will obviously start producing garbage results.

So instead, keep your own extra Vector 2 handy for this.

```
private final Vector2 unprojectedTouchPos = new Vector2();
```

Then copy the touch position vector into this vector on each frame and use this one instead:

```
public void handleInput(Application app)
{
    if (input.touchDown)
    {
        unprojectedTouchPos.set(input.screenTouchPos);
        app.viewport.unproject(unprojectedTouchPos);
        position.x = unprojectedTouchPos.x - sprite.getWidth() / 2;
    }
}
```

---

**Edit:**
Based on your comments, you also want the position to update in real-time as the finger drags, so add this to your InputProcessor's `touchDragged` method:

```
screenTouchPos.set(screenX, screenY);
```

Comment: i tried it, but it doesnt continueosly match the x-axis. only the first time it will go to the touch place. to get an action again i have to let it go and hold it down again.

Comment: Add this to your InputProcessor's `touchDragged` method: `screenTouchPos.set(screenX, screenY);`

Comment: it worked! consider editing the answer with the comment so the answer is complete